# dateutil and leap years

Tags: python, python-dateutil

If I have the following list of strings:

```
a = ['Loc_RaffertytoLong_2004_02_21',
 'Loc_RaffertytoLong_2004_02_22',
 'Loc_RaffertytoLong_2004_02_23',
 'Loc_RaffertytoLong_2004_02_24',
 'Loc_RaffertytoLong_2004_02_26',
 'Loc_RaffertytoLong_2004_02_27',
 'Loc_RaffertytoLong_2004_02_28',
 'Loc_RaffertytoLong_2004_02_29']
```

And I try to parse the date using `dateutil`:

```
from dateutil import parse as dparse
for i in a:
    print(dparse.parse(i,fuzzy=True))
```

I get the printout:

```
2019-02-21 00:00:00
2019-02-22 00:00:00
2019-02-23 00:00:00
2019-02-24 00:00:00
2019-02-26 00:00:00
2019-02-27 00:00:00
2019-02-28 00:00:00
```

And the error:

```
ValueError: ('Unknown string format:', 'Loc_RaffertytoLong_2004_02_29')
```

I am not sure why since 2004 is a leap year.

Comment: Update: A `dateutil` PR has been submitted for review to resolve this issue.  Check out my [github issue](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/issues/959) for additional details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at your output, `dateutil` is interpreting your dates as dates in 2019 (which is *not* a leap year).

I was able to get your code to succeed by changing the line:

```
print(dparse.parse(i,fuzzy=True))
```

to:

```
print(dparse.parse('-'.join(i.split('_')[2:])))
```

and when I run the whole block, I get the output:

```
2004-02-21 00:00:00
2004-02-22 00:00:00
2004-02-23 00:00:00
2004-02-24 00:00:00
2004-02-26 00:00:00
2004-02-27 00:00:00
2004-02-28 00:00:00
2004-02-29 00:00:00
```

---

Interestingly, if we join on underscores like so:

```
print(dparse.parse('_'.join(i.split('_')[2:])))
```

it also interprets the dates as in the year 2019. This makes me think the issue is with how `dateutil` handles underscores.

---

You can also simply replace the underscores with dashes:

```
from dateutil import parser
for i in a:
    print(parser.parse(i.replace('_','-'), fuzzy=True))
```

prints the same output as above.

Comment: Replacing underscores with dashes before `dparse.parse` is a great suggestion.

Comment: I'm a little surprised that dateutil doesn't recognize underscores as a valid delimiter tbh

Comment: I agree. I just submitted a github issue.